# How to assign ClientCredentials to WCF Client while binding with Ninject Kernel in Test_at_server configuration?

Tags: wcf, binding, dependency-injection, ninject, credentials

I am using Ninject to inject my WCF client in the local environment and its working fine. This is how
I have implemented it:

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);

        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        RegisterServices(kernel);
        return kernel;
    }
```

and in my `RegisterServices(kernel)` method I have the follwing implementation:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
    #if DEBUG
        kernel.Bind<MyWCFClient.IMyWCF>().To<MyWCFClient.MyWCFClient>();

    #elif Test_at_server            
        kernel.Bind<MyWCFClient.IMyWCF>().To<MyWCFClient.MyWCFClient>()
              /*.WithConstructorArgument("UserName", Credentials.UserName.UserName = "user")
              .WithConstructorArgument("Password", Credentials.UserName.Password = "password")*/;
    #endif
    }
```

What I am trying to do is, when I am deploying my web application in the server, ninject should 
inject the WCf with the Credentials because the WCF at server needs to be authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this and it works for me!

```
#if DEBUG
    kernel.Bind<MyWCFClient.IMyWCF>().To<MyWCFClient.MyWCFClient>();
    #elif Test_at_server
    ClientCredentials Credentials = new ClientCredentials();
    kernel.Bind<MyWCFClient.IMyWCF>().To<MyWCFClient.MyWCFClient>()
        .WithConstructorArgument("UserName", Credentials.UserName.UserName = "username")
       .WithConstructorArgument("Password", Credentials.UserName.Password = "password");
#else
#endif
```